# Redis : How to update map 1 based on expiration in map 2?

Tags: redis

I have two redis maps where I maintain counts of two related keys.

In map1 I set the TTL as 5 minutes , and increment the count in both map1 and map2.

Now what I want is, once the key expires in map1 , I wish to reduce count in map2.

From my initial analysis, I think Keyspace notifications are the way to go for this. By setting a subscriber which will read events for expired key and then decrement count accordingly.

However , is there any other way to implement it ? I don't want to use a pub-sub model for this one, I was wondering if redis has any functionality which would let me decrement count after x time. I will know the x time.

Comment: Currently that's the only way. In redis 5.0 it would be possible to implement this as a module pretty easily so you will not depend on a connected client for it.

Comment: True and correct of course but regardless v5, keep in mind that PubSub is not a guaranteed message delivery service, so your subscriber may loose messages and thus an inconsistency may be born.

Comment: Any idea how much % of the keys can I expect to have inconsistency ?